# How can I draw the following figure in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following figure in latex

[image]

Please let me know the syntax for this

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Using the `ifsym` package: `------ {\tiny\textifsymbol[ifgeo]{102}} ------`

Answer (score 2):

For a starting point.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, fill, minimum width = 0.5cm, minimum height = 0.5cm, rotate=45] (N)  {};
\draw [thick]([xshift=-1mm]N.135)--++(180:2) ([xshift=1mm]N.-45)--++(0:2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]